# Read entire string by the serial port in C#

Tags: c#, .net, readline

HI guys

I'm trying to read a string that send by the serial port, I was using readline() function first but as the string has multiple lines, I have to loop, How do i determent that i reached end of the string, or is there a way i can read the entire string using other then readline that not depending on the new line.

Thank you

Jp

Comment: Are you using a stream?  Can you show a little of your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no magic ways other than protocols used over the wire.

If you are sending from the other endpoint, you need to add something at the end of the string that tells the receiving end point that everything have been sent.

If you have not developed the other end point, you need to ask the manufacture/developer how you can determine then end of string.

A pretty standard way to mark beginning and ending of serial messages is to use the ASCII characters STX/ETX (0x2 and 0x3 in the ASCII table)

Answer (score 1):

ETA: This isn't a good idea, since you don't know when you reach the end of the string.

I don't know about the serial port aspect, but assuming you have a Stream and all the data is available, you can wrap it in a StreamReader and call [ReadToEnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readtoend.aspx).

Comment: And how would he know when everything have been read by doing so? It's not a file.

Comment: You're absolutely right, looking at the docs/rethinking the situation. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I have to force some identification tell me the end of the string